# I want to get number of items in a nested unsizes array of structures.what can I do for that?

Tags: c

```
struct store
{
 ...
 struct item
 {
  ...
 }it[];
 struct employee
 {
  ...
 }e[];
}s[];
```

Here I want to know how many items was stored after gets input for structure item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C doesn't have a concept of "array size" for a non-bounded array. In fact, its concept of arrays is shaky at best.

The two options that are generally used are:

1. Have a "length" attribute stored alongside the array
2. Zero-terminate the array, i.e. the pointer after the last element is zero

For your case, I'd recommend the first of the two:

```
struct mydatastruct
{
    int store_length;
    struct store
    {
        ...
        int item_length;
        struct item
        {
            ...
        } it[];
        int employee_length;
        struct employee    {
            ...
        } e[];
    } s[];
} mystruct;
```